# Why does python throw a name-error for function parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, parameters, python-2.x

When I run

```
def classMaker(x):
    class y(object):
        x=x
    return y

Y = classMaker("value")
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bug.py", line 6, in <module>
    classMaker("value")
  File "bug.py", line 2, in classMaker
    class y(object):
  File "bug.py", line 3, in y
    x=x
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

but `x="value"`. What's going on?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate, good discussion in the answer above.

Comment: That duplicate gets a frustrating number of nuances wrong; for example, edit 5 in the question thinks that class scopes can't access variables from enclosing function scopes at all.

Answer (score 1):

Name lookup at class scope is weird and not really consistent with its documentation.

Normally, unlike with a function scope, name lookup in a class scope happens the same regardless of whether the scope has assignments to the name; locals first, then globals, then builtins. However, nonlocal lookup in a class scope *is* affected by assignments in that class scope.

If you do something like

```
def classMaker(x):
    class y(object):
        z=x  # not x=x
    return y
```

Python sees that the name `x` matches a nonlocal variable, and it uses the `LOAD_DEREF` opcode to access the closure cell for that variable. However, the assignment to `x` in your actual code:

```
def classMaker(x):
    class y(object):
        x=x
    return y
```

causes Python to use `LOAD_NAME`, the usual opcode for class-scope name lookup, which doesn't see closure variables.

Answer (score -1):

It's not equal. You undeclaring it by assigment and trying to assign to new, undefined variable. Use another name.

```
def classMaker(z):
    class y(object):
        x=z
    return y

Y = classMaker("value")
```

Comment: why can't we use x=x can you explain it bit more in function we can use it right why not here???